# Display my carriers error

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a module that adds carriers obtained through an external web service. The ADDICTION to the database is done correctly and in phpmyadmin shown carrier created.
However, the screen carriers not shown the carriers installed and print out the following line error:

> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\db\Db.php on line 815

The complete method code is:

```
public function installCarriers()
    {        
        $id_lang_default = Language::getIsoById(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $envios = Configuration::get('ENVIOS');
        foreach ($envios as $env) 
        {                
                $carrier = new Carrier();
                $carrier->name = $env->nombreModo;
                $carrier->id_tax_rules_group = 0;
                $carrier->active = TRUE;
                $carrier->deleted = 0;
                foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $language)
                   $carrier->delay[(int)$language['id_lang']] = $env->periodo_dia;
                $carrier->shipping_handling = false;
                $carrier->range_behavior = 0;
                $carrier->is_module = true;
                $carrier->is_free = false;
                $carrier->shipping_external = false;
                $carrier->external_module_name = (string)$this->name;
                $carrier->need_range = true;

                if ($carrier->add())
                {
                    // Associate carrier to all groups
                    $groups = Group::getGroups(true);
                    foreach ($groups as $group)
                        Db::getInstance()->insert('carrier_group', array('id_carrier' => (int)$carrier->id, 'id_group' => (int)$group['id_group']));

                    // Create price range
                    $aux1 = intval($env->precioBase);
                    $aux2 = $aux1+1;
                    $rangePrice = new RangePrice();
                    $rangePrice->id_carrier = $carrier->id;
                    $rangePrice->delimiter1 = $aux1;
                    $rangePrice->delimiter2 = $aux2;   
                    $rangePrice->add();

                    // Crear el rango de pesos para el carrier
                    $rangeWeight = new RangeWeight();
                    $rangeWeight->id_carrier = $carrier->id;
                    $rangeWeight->delimiter1 = '0';
                    $rangeWeight->delimiter2 = '10000';
                    $rangeWeight->add();

                    //Calculo del precio incluyendo el IVA (21%)
                    $priceIVA = str_replace(',', '.', $env->precioBase);
                    $priceIVA = (float)$priceIVA + (float)$priceIVA*(float)0.21;

                    // Asociar el carrier a la zona 1 = Europa
                    $zone = Zone::getIdByName('Europe');
                    Db::getInstance()->insert('carrier_zone', array('id_carrier' => (int)$carrier->id, 'id_zone' => (int)$zone));
                    Db::getInstance()->insert('delivery', array('id_carrier' => (int)$carrier->id, 'id_range_price' => (int)$rangePrice->id, 'id_range_weight' => (int)$rangeWeight->id, 'id_zone' => (int)$zone, 'price' => $priceIVA));



                    // Copy the carrier logo
                    copy(dirname(__FILE__).'/views/img/'.$env->urlEmpresa, _PS_SHIP_IMG_DIR_.'/'.(int)$carrier->id.'.jpg');

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are setting a "string" variable with an array. Check all the variables before you call add() function.

Answer (score 0):

Check your object variables (fields in the definition array), avoid multiselect values and give the array instead of string value (array => string).